# How to use Arraylist to populate Graphview Line Graph

Tags: java, android, android-graphview

I currently have a program that generates an Arraylist that I would like to represent on a Line Graph via Graphview. While instantiating the points of the graph, I get syntactical errors that I don't quite understand.

I've attempted to use the sample code from: https://github.com/jjoe64/GraphView/wiki/simple-graph as sort of basis for instantiating data points for a line graph, but when I attempt my own instantiation (via for-loop of my arraylist of data), I get unexpected token errors. I've tried moving around parentheses and brackets and I'm sure it's something simple that I'm missing, but I'm stuck at the moment.

```java
//Example code I am utilizing for populating data points into graph
GraphView graph = (GraphView) findViewById(R.id.graph);
LineGraphSeries<DataPoint> series = new LineGraphSeries<>(new DataPoint[] {
          new DataPoint(0, 1),
          new DataPoint(1, 5),
          new DataPoint(2, 3),
          new DataPoint(3, 2),
          new DataPoint(4, 6)
});
graph.addSeries(series);

//My version of populating data points into graph
 GraphView graph = (GraphView) findViewById(R.id.graph);
        LineGraphSeries<DataPoint> series = new LineGraphSeries<>(new DataPoint[]{
                for (int i = 0; i < timerObjs.size(); i++) {
                    new DataPoint(i, timerObjs.get(i));
                }
        });
graph.addSeries(series);
```

[image: 1]]

- The first error is ')' expected, '}' expected
- The second error is ';' expected
- The third error is Unexpected Tokens

What I don't understand is why the errors from the first and second line are not resolved by the last error (what it perceives as unexpected tokens)

Answer (score 0):

Found my own solution, linking answer for anyone having similar issues in future: https://github.com/jjoe64/GraphView/issues/488